# Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}^2$ is convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|{a_n}|}{n\sqrt n}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to prove that if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}^2$ is convergent, then the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|{a_n}|}{n\sqrt n}$$
 is convergent?

Comment: I edited the question, but I'm not sure if I changed the OP's question in the process.

Comment: If on the other hand you want to prove that $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\lvert a_n\rvert}{n\sqrt{n}}$$ converges, you need far far less than the convergence of $\sum a_n^2$.

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, anything in $\ell^2$ is fine.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to proove.

Comment: Then note that the convergence of $\sum a_n^2$ implies the boundedness of $\lvert a_n\rvert$.

Comment: you know that $\langle x,y \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^N x_n y_n$ is bounded by the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality) $|\langle x,y \rangle| \le \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N x_n^2}\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^Ny_n^2}$. Well with $N = \infty$ it works the same way

Comment: @Maria The answer you saw fit to (instantly) accept is flawed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- As a $p$-series with $p=\frac{3}{2}>1$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$ is convergent. (Indeed, recall that $n\sqrt{n}=n^{3/2}$).
- Now, since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ is convergent by assumption, we have the necessary condition $a_n^2\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$.
  This implies that $\lvert a_n \rvert\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$, and in turn that the sequence $(\lvert a_n \rvert)_n$ is bounded: there exists $M>0$ such that $0\leq \lvert a_n \rvert \leq M$ for any $n\geq 1$.
- Combining the two, we get $\frac{ \lvert a_n \rvert}{n\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{M}{n\sqrt{n}}$, and you can conclude by theorems of comparisons for series with non-negative terms.